# Jenkins EMail-ext plugin sends groovy code in the Email body

Tags: email, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

The 'Default Content' of Extended E-mail Notification is set as below and Default Content Type is 'HTML (text/html)':

```
<html>
<body>
<%
    if(build.testResultAction) {
        def testResult = build.testResultAction
        def testCount = String.format("%.2f",(testResult.totalCount))
        def testPassed = String.format("%.2f",())
        def testFailed = String.format("%.2f",(testResult.result.failCount))
        def testSkipped = String.format("%.2f",())
        def buildDuration = String.format("%.2f",(testResult.result.duration ))
    }
%>
Hi All,<br><br>

The execution of the Automation suite has been completed and the results are as below.<br><br>

<b><u>Configuration :</u></b><br>
Project Name : $JOB_NAME<br>
Test Server URL : $Test_Server_URL<br>
Group Name : $Group_Name<br><br>

<b><u>Execution Results :</u></b><br>
Status : <font color="blue">$BUILD_STATUS</font><br>
Tests run : $testCount<br>
Failures : $testFailed<br>
Errors : 0<br>
Skipped : 0<br>
Total time : $buildDuration<br>
Finished at: Tue May 06 17:12:19 IST 2014<br>
Build URL : $BUILD_URL<br><br>

The HTML version of the automation results and the log file is attached with this e-mail for your reference.<br><br>

Regards,<br>
Jenkins CI Tool
</body>
</html>
```

But the report e-mail has the groovy code itself in its body rather than the expected values.

Comment: By the way, if this script is put in test.groovy and run under email-ext plugin as per instructions with answer from @Akos Bannerth below then we get exception on lines 7 and 9 . . missing something ?                  """Exception raised during template rendering: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed: SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy: 7: unexpected token: ) @ line 7, column 48. assed = String.format("%.2f",()) ^ 1"""

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the wiki page of the [emai-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Scriptcontent) about using script content, the steps are described there:

1. Put your groovy script into a file
2. Place it on the jenkins master, under `JENKINS_HOME/email-templates/`
3. In the email configuration use the script token replacing the content: `${SCRIPT, template="name-of-template"}`

Answer (score 1):

For reference here is the sample code by @Vel Ganesh with syntax fixed.
This is rough but working with jenkins 2.7.4 Jan 2017).

Follow the answer by @Akos Bannerth. 
Put groovy script into test.groovy file.

```
<html>
<body>
<%

    import hudson.model.*

    def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
    def buildNumber = build.number
    def buildNameJ = build.getDisplayName()

    def testCount = "0"
    def testPassed = "0"
    def testFailed = "0"
    def testSkipped = "0"
    def buildDuration = "0"
    if(build.testResultAction) {
        def testResult = build.testResultAction
        testCount = String.format("%d",(testResult.totalCount))
        testPassed = String.format("%d",(testResult.result.passCount))
        testFailed = String.format("%d",(testResult.result.failCount))
        testSkipped = String.format("%d",(testResult.result.skipCount))
        buildDuration = String.format("%.2f",(testResult.result.duration ))
    }

    def workspace = build.getEnvVars()["WORKSPACE"]
    def buildName = build.getEnvVars()["JOB_NAME"]
    def BUILD_STATUS = build.getEnvVars()["BUILD_STATUS"]
    def BUILD_URL = build.getEnvVars()["BUILD_URL"]
    def Test_Server_URL  = build.getEnvVars()["Test_Server_URL"]
    def Group_Name = build.getEnvVars()["Group_Name"]
%>

Summary test report <br><br>

<b><u>Configuration :</u></b><br>
Workspace : $workspace<br>
Project Name : $buildName  $buildNameJ<br>
Test Server URL : $Test_Server_URL<br>
Group Name : $Group_Name<br><br>

<b><u>Execution Results :</u></b><br>
Status : <font color="blue">$BUILD_STATUS</font><br>
Tests run : $testCount<br>
Failures : $testFailed<br>
Errors : . . . TODO . . . <br>
Skipped : $testSkipped<br>
Total time : $buildDuration<br>
Finished at: Tue May 06 17:12:19 IST 2014<br>
Build URL : $BUILD_URL<br><br>

test.groovy

</body>
</html>
```